# phpUnit test issue does not run

Tags: php, unit-testing

I am just implementing  now phpunit test Unit in my project .I have already installed phpunit through composer on my computer.and after I wrote a small unit test script aS illustrated below to run a test.

```
namespace TestNamespace;
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

// class to be used to run test 
class algo
{
   private $x;
   private $y;

  function __construct($x,$y)
  {
     $this->x = $x ;
     $this->y = $y ;
  }

  function getSom()
  {
    return ($this->x + $this->y) ;
  }
}


// writting test for phpUnit
class somTest extends TestCase
{

   function testValue()
   {
      $som = new algo(10,20);

      $this->assertEquals(30,$som->getSom());
   }
}
```

**First question is there any fault in the script above ?**

Below you will see what happen when I type  either ***phpunit somTest.php*** or ***phpunit somTest*** to run the test.
[image]

Can someone help me?

Comment: Put the code in different files, and include `algo` class into `somTest.php`

Comment: I ran your script and works as intended: `OK (1 test, 1 assertion)` (PHPUnit 5.4.6)

Comment: @Syscall what have you typed to run the test?

Comment: @Felippe Duarte ok I place algo in another file but the problem occurs

Comment: Just like you `phpunit somTest.php`. I suggest you to get a newest version of PHPUnit.

Comment: PHPUnit 3.7.21 is the version I use but in my composer.json it is mentioned 
  require-dev :{ "phpunit/phpunit": "^5.7" }

Comment: If you've installed it via Composer as well, it sounds like you might have two versions running, and the default one in your path is the (very) old one. Try `vendor/bin/phpunit somTest.php` - that'll use the one that Composer installed.